# Finding a Percentile with formulae

Tags: statistics

I have ten ordered values : 2,3,5,6,8,10,12,15,18,20. The excercise asks for the 60th percentile. I used the percentile formula to get the "c value"(position in the data set) $c=\frac{n.p}{100}$, and I get 6 as the c value, then I look for the sixth position in my data set and add it with the "c+1 value", then dividing the outcome by 2 I get 11 as the value that corresponds to 60th percentile.

The actual issue is that when I try to reverse the "thing", using the formula $\frac{(number of values below X) + 0.5}{(total number of values)}*100$ and using "c value = 6" as the X value in this formula I can't get the 60th percentile, instead I get 55th percentile, that is driving me crazy, even if I use the 7 as c value I still can't get the 60th percentile

Comment: Method in first paragraph is clear enough. Can't make sense of the formula in your second paragraph. (Confusion between count and data value?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different texts and software packages have a variety of formulas for percentiles. The differences can be quite noticeable for small datasets such as yours, but they are not so noticeable for large datasets.

Roughly speaking the idea is to sort the data and then try to find a dividing point
(which need not be one of the data values) that has about 60% of the data below
and about 40% above. That works just fine if you have a sample size divisible by $10$ and no ties. Otherwise, compromises need to be made. And there is no
general agreement about the compromises.

In R statistical software, one can specify different rules. The 'default' rule
(in effect without making special requests) gives the following results
for your data.

```
x = c(2,3,5,6,8,10,12,15,18,20)
quantile(x, .60)
##   60% 
##  10.8
```

But for your data, any number between 10 and 12 would do nicely.

Comment: So, I can gather form this explanation that whether I try to reverse the method starting from 10.8 using the second formula I wrote, the outcome would not give the 60% value, that is, when compromises are being used this reverse thing doesn't work

Comment: Some version of the 'reverse thing' might be OK, but I confess I don't understand the notation in that. The 55th percentile should be btw 8 and 10;  for example, in R `quantile(x, .55)` returns 9.9.